# How to send mail without a delay

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to send mails to 5 people with different messages. I'm sending a mail using SMTP, using below code to send mail but it has some delay because of this getting late response. How can i send mail without delay?

Here is the Code i'm using

```
$email  = '';
$from  = '';
$subject  = '';
$message  = 'Message';

$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => '',
    'smtp_pass' => '',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'utf-8'
);
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from($from, '');
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
$result = $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Email is not _instant_. It takes some time to be routed correctly. This may also be a rate limit imposed by Google. Try using a different mail provider. Your code would not cause delays.

Comment: Sending 5 different message to 5 different people in just a snap of finger is not possible in real world like you wish. It will cost some time as usual.